# How to free char array in struct

Tags: c

I see that you can free char * pointers within struct but how do you free char[N] inside a struct

```
typedef struct Edge
{
    char number[13];
    int numOfCalls;
    struct Edge *next;
} Edge;
```

When I do this i get an error

```
Edge *edge = malloc(sizeof(Edge));
edge->next = NULL;
strcpy(edge->number,numberOne);  // numberOne is also a char[13];
free(edge->number);
free(edge);
```

Comment: You don't have to, you use `free` with ponters pointing to a (m/re/c)alloced area. Here `number` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use char array (`char number[13]`) in struct, you don't have to `malloc` or `free` the array. Once you do `malloc` for struct Edge, there is also space for number in memory.

In summary, if you use char pointer as a member of `struct Edge`, you need to `malloc` or `free` memory space for char pointer, but you don't have to do that in your case. Therefore, delete `free(edge->number)` line.

Answer (score 0):

The lifespan of `number` in the struct `Edge` is automatic. Even if you dynamically allocate an `Edge` struct, when you `free` the struct, you'll free the memory for the char array.

Comment: The lifetime of the structure whose memory was reserved with `malloc` is *allocated*, not *automatic*, and so too is the lifetime of any member within it.

Comment: Indeed. However, I was sitting of the char array within the struct.